# Translation help with って

Tags: grammar

He was asked if he liked to read an replied:

> 「あはは、そんな優雅な趣味はしてないよ。自分では落ち着いているって気もしないんだけど、メガネをかけてるとそういうイメージが先行するのかもしれないね」
>
> [Ahahah, I don't have such an elegant hobby. I do not feel like I am calm by myself though, the fact that I have glasses could make you think that tough]

It does not make much sense, I am not sure if this is correct.

自分では [By me]
落ち着いている[Be calm]
って気もしないんだ [Do not feel]
けど[But]
、メガネをかけてる[Having glasses]
と[Conditional]
そういうイメージが先行するの[That image has priority]
かもしれないね[maybe]

This is how I think it is.
Any corrections or help?

Comment: Who was asked if he liked to read? And your translations should should go 'I do not feel I am calm by myself, but ...'

Comment: The one who is talking was asked by his sister's maid if he liked to read.
He answered that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is almost exactly what you think.

って acts as a casual quoting particle in this case, meaning "For/By (では) me, I don't even (indicated by も) feel calm. However, by wearing glasses, that kind of image (referring to image of wearing glasses) might make you think so."

先行する may also be somewhat confusing because the dictionary doesn't provide the 'priority' definition that you have stated. In this case, it means "precede", referring to the image of him wearing glasses preceding the fact that he is not being calm.